# Quick flash pop-up installation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have been searching for a solution for a while now, and have not found the right one. 

I was hoping you guys can help...
I have a simple landing page using flash on it, and I want to be able to detect if  visitors to this LP have flash installed to view it with, and if not, I want them to be able for them to install Flash from this landing page with this pop-up below.

[image: pop-up example]

how can i do that for IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) offers this capability

You can use hasPlayerVersion() to detect the version:

```
if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9")) { }
```

Checkout Step 3 on this page:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation
to learn how to use swfobject to run your plugin installer